# How to abstract this single case (showing text field based on selection of a drop down list) into a general function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first detailed question on SO.

Hi, so I have a form and have many instances where I want to show a text field after a drop down list when the user selects the "Other" option in the drop down list.

I am using a standard naming convention and am wondering, do I have to have as many functions as DDL/text field pairs in the document, or can I have a single function I can call on a class of DDLs?  Here's the HTML:

```
<label for="spotter">Spotter:</label>
<select id="spotter" required>
    <option value="Snoop Dogg">Snoop Dogg</option>
    <option value="MC Escher">MC Escher</option>
    <option value="Linus Thorvalds">Linus Thorvalds</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br/>

<div id="spotter_other_div"><label for="spotter_other">Other Spotter:</label><br><input type="text" name="spotter_other" id="spotter_other" size="50" required/></div>
```

and here's the jQuery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#spotter").change(function () {
        //alert("You just changed the value of the #spotter drop down menu.");
        if ($(this).val() == "Other" )
            //alert("You just changed the value of the #spotter drop down menu to 'Other.'");
            $("#spotter_other_div").css("visibility", "visible");
        else
            $("#spotter_other_div").css("visibility", "collapse");
    });     
});
```

The initial state of the div containing the text field is "collapse" in css.

I am learning jQuery and I'm at the point where I know how to do something for a general case, and I'd like to see if this is a function I can write, or if I have to do it explicitly.

Note that the page is a work in progress so any suggestions are welcome (e.g. use a span instead of a div to contain the text field, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just use a single function with some code and call it multiple times...  Hence the purpose of functions: Reusable bits of code.

Comment: If the answer I gave you is the one you were looking for, be sure to mark it as the correct one. ;)

Comment: They're both correct but I prefer the other one.  Thanks for the reminder though, I marked it.

Comment: Sweet!  Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here.

1. Create a function and parametrize it out.  This is what Sethen Maleno's answer shows.
2. Make your function a more general function.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    // Apply this to every select element
    $("select").change(function () {
        // Dynamically build up the selector to show/hide
        var secondMenuId = '#' + $(this).attr(id) + '_other_div'
        if ($(this).val() == "Other" )
            $(secondMenuId).css("visibility", "visible");
        else
            $(secondMenuId).css("visibility", "collapse");
    });     
});
```

Note that this approach requires discipline when you generate your HTML, and that the ids are assigned appropriately (which you seem to be doing since you mention using a standard naming convention).

This approach has the advantage that this is the only code you would have, and you wouldn't need to write lots of handlers.

Sethen's gives you a little more flexibility in that your ids wouldn't need to follow strict conventions (you could pass whatever you wanted as arguments), but does require you to write a function call to attach it to every item you want.

Both techniques are valid and have their time and place.

Comment: I like this option because you're right, I do adhere to a strict naming convention, and it also accounts for DDLs that don't have an "Other" option, in which case nothing happens.  I just checked and I don't have any such DDLs but if I do, I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a single function with some code and call it multiple times (or once if you're using the same `id` or `class`)... Hence the purpose of functions: Reusable bits of code.  Here's what it might look like.

```
$(function () { //shorthand for ready in jQuery
    //set up your function
    function dropDownOther(spotter, spotterDiv) { //function takes two args
        $(spotter).change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
                $(spotterDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {
                $(spotterDiv).css("visibility", "collapse");
            }
        });
    }
    dropDownOther("#spotter", "#spotter_other_div"); //call your function
    dropDownOther("#otherSelector", "#otherSelectorTwo"); //call it again if necessary 
});
```